# Haskell Ord instance paradox on Eq

Tags: haskell, equality, polynomials

I want to be able to order Polynomes with comparing first by lenght (degree), second by coefficient. Polynomes are list of doubles with `[1,2,3] = 3x²+2x+1` .
But if there is a zero as last element it should be dropped, so I wrote a function doing that called `realPolynom`. `realPolynom [1,2,3,0] = [1,2,3]`
Now, my Ord instance looks like:

```
instance Ord Polynom where                                  
    compare a b = compare ((realLength a), reverse (pol2list (realPolynom a))) ((realLength b), reverse (pol2list (realPolynom b)))
```

`realLength` is just Length of polynom without zeros as last.

```
pLength :: Polynom -> Int       
pLength (Polynom(a)) = length a

realLength :: Polynom -> Int                        
realLength a = pLength(realPolynom(a))
```

`pol2list` is `Polynom p = p`

```
pol2list :: Polynom -> [Double]
pol2list (Polynom p) = p
```

Problem is:

- `[0,2,0] < [0,2,3]` true, which is good
- `[0,2,0] < [0,2]` false, also good
- `[0,2,0] > [0,2]` false, also good
- `[0,2,0] == [0,2]` false, which is not good! should be equal!

Comment: Why are you reversing the polynoms as lists? Also, `reverse $ pol2list $ realPolynom b` is usually more clear than `reverse (pol2list (realPolynom b)))`.

Comment: I agree, looks clearer. I am doing it, as ist needs to compare last elemts first, and my own datatype cannot be reversed

Comment: Have you tried using `compare [0,2,0] [0,2]` instead of `==`?

Comment: Just a side note: you could define `compare = comparing realLength <> comparing (reverse . pol2list . realPolynom)`, where `<>` is an alias for `mappend` from `Data.Monoid` and monoids in play are `a -> b` and `Ordering`.

Comment: Where is your Eq instance?

Comment: @Merphy yes, compare `[0,2,0] [0,2] = EQ`. So shouldnt it give TRUE with `==`? @fizruk thanks, I'll def have a look at that

Comment: @n.m. it's `datatype ... deriving (Show,Eq)`

Comment: @Krismu there's your problem.  Don't derive Eq, implement it atop your Ord instance.

Comment: You should write your own `EQ instance` ...
The derived one doesn't know anything about your `Ord` instance.

Comment: I tried that already resulting `error:no memory` making GHCi to crash though it could compile and load the .hs without problem. The code was `instance Eq Polynom where 
 a == b = (realPolynom a) == (realPolynom b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
instance Eq Polynom where
    x == y = pol2list (realPolynom x) == pol2list (realPolynom y)
```

Unfortunately, in this case the derived `Eq` instance is not the intended one.

Comment: Thanks again, so what I tried was `x==y = (realPolynom x) == (realPolynom y)` causing GHCi to crash. Works with your fix now, I didnt see that again I am comparing Polynomes in my instance...

Answer (score 7):

Instead of deriving Eq, you should probably write

```
instance Eq Polynom where
  a == b = compare a b == EQ
```

Answer (score 4):

The best solution might be to ensure that no leading zeroes ever turn up in the first place. I.e. instead of ever building polynomes manually from lists, you feed them to a "smart constructor" that eats away zeroes before packing the `Polynome` data type.

May seem a bit of a OO-ish thing to do, but sometimes this kind of encapsulation is just the way to go, even in functional languages.

Comment: Not in the least OO-ish. After all, what do modules like Data.Map or Data.Ratio do? Exactly this: hiding implementation behind a façade of functions!